# Cosmos DB sql query to get highest value pr day

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Im relatively new to cosmos db. I have created a database of temperature measurements where new value are added every 5 minutes.

Here is an example of an item in the collection:

```json
{
   "id": "3445609a-c4ae-44b3-b8fa-a2e55082558b",
   "temp": 14.31,
   "timestamp": "2020-09-24T18:56:48.7828653+00:00",
   "probeid": "01",
   "lightvalue": "0",
   "RelativeHumidity": "50.10"
}
```

I initially added the timestamp value before learning that the `_ts` value could be used for this.

Im still in the logic design phase trying to figure out the best pattern to use in order to make this stabile, and low resource cost.

Use case would be: Max, Min, Avg measurements pr day within a given period presented in a webUI.

Comment: How many devices are there and how often are you querying for this data? Also are you going to query for all devices and their highest temperatures or one device at a time?

Comment: The `_ts` property is related to the timestamp that your data is written, and is unrelated to an actual timestamp of your choosing (e.g. when the reading took place), so there's nothing wrong with you having your own explicit timestamp. That said: Please edit your question to show what you've tried so far. Also, how are you partitioning your data? (this will play an important role in performance, when doing aggregations). You should examine `GROUP BY`, and also consider how you would identify individual days based on data stored.

Comment: @MarkBrown I so far only have 1 device posting measurements, and this is a toy project. But still I will try to make it ready for scale so supporting multiple devices. But to answer your question directly Pr device highest temperature for a given peiriod i.e week or month

Comment: @DavidMakogon There is very little latency form measurement to posting to DB, so ._ts would be sufficient as a timestamp.
Im having trouble wrapping my head arround how to structure this in a query. I started building a query that lists all ._ts within a given time period pulled from the .timestamp but that seemed very slow.
I also though of building a seperate "table" to store the high/low/avg value pr day and just have a timed task to go through the measurement one day at time. This would allow for good performance when reading the values, and they never change back in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this SQL achieve your requirement?

```
 SELECT MAX(c.temp) as max_temp,MIN(c.temp) as min_temp,AVG(c.temp) AS average_temp,LEFT(toString(TimestampToDateTime(c._ts*1000)),10) AS day  
 FROM c 
 WHERE c._ts*1000 < GetCurrentTimestamp() 
 GROUP BY LEFT(toString(TimestampToDateTime(c._ts*1000)),10)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing - when I run this query in the Query explorer within the azure portal it gives me this error: {"code":400,"body":"{\"code\":\"BadRequest\",\"message\":\"Message: {\\\"Errors\\\":[\\\"Cross partition query only supports 'VALUE <AggreateFunc>' for aggregates.\\\"]}\\r\\nActivityId: 0d44a954-feab-4638-9653-79e8b874e556, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.11.0\"}","activityId":"0d44a954-feab-4638-9653-79e8b874e556"}

Comment: I tried using your query from code, and here it worked fine. Thank you so much I am super impressed with some people's ability to think in sql, a skill iI will never master :-)

Comment: Works in cosmos data explorer. Nice bit of SQL, thank you.